# Running an passed function and passport.authenticate

Tags: node.js, jwt, backend, passport.js

I want both the function that sets the JWT and the `passport.authenticate` to run but only the former is running.

Is there a way I can have both run?

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {

   const userEmail = req.body.username;

   User.getUserByEmail(userEmail, function(err, user) {

     const token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
       expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
     });
     new Cookies(req, res).set('access_tokenx', token, {
       httpOnly: true,
       secure: false
     });
     return res.send();
   });
 },
 passport.authenticate('local', {
   successRedirect: '/',
   failureRedirect: '/users/login',
   failureFlash: true
 }),
 function(req, res) {
   res.redirect('/');
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `express` [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html):

> If the current middleware function does not end the request-response
>   cycle, it must call **next()** to pass control to the next middleware
>   function.

Since you're trying to run two middleware functions and one "final" request processor, you should replace `return res.send();` with `next()` in the function that sets the JWT.

Also keep in mind that if any errors arise you should call `next(err)`. (You should never allow a request to go unhandled in a middleware function because the client will never receive a response).

Comment: It worked perfectly, Thank you so much, this has been causing be troubles for ages. I wish you luck in all you do, have an awesome day, week, month, year and life man!